# Rest service for mobile apps and interactive website

Tags: django, rest, mobile

Hi I am currently redesigning our mobile application. Currently my phone application is doing a url request to my server which is returning a json which then gets absorbed and the data is used accordingly.

The website that interacts with the same kinds of data as well.

I was wondering that if I should create a rest service what makes it different from just having the server output jsons given specific parameters. I was planning on using django to implement this but was wondering what the benefits are of using something like django-piston when django has a rest framework built into it.

Also is creating a rest service a good way for phones and websites to interact with each other?

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely should have a look at this Django REST Framework.
I used to use tastypie... but especially because of the easyness of up- and downloading files (images) and the browsable api, i switched to using this one:

[django-rest-framework.org](http://django-rest-framework.or)

I Am using it for interacting with mobile applications (but also the old fashioned thick clients, in my case in java....)

Answer (score 0):

Because if you write REST, you can do stuff like this:

[The Richardson Maturity Model: Four degrees of REST](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html)